# How do I get the merge request information in the pre-receive hook?

Tags: git, gitlab, pre-commit-hook

I need to catch the pushes and merges in GitLab on the server side and reject them if they do not have one of two labels.

To do this I intend using the API to check the merge request's details.

The pre-receive hook has the SHA1s of the file changes and the branch name but how do I get the project and merge request numbers so I can check the labels using the APIs?

Comment: @LeGEC, each directory is a number (I assume the MR number?) so would I have to search through each directory comparing SHA1 numbers to the file contents or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I think my previous comments weren't suited for your need, you can get the info you need in your `pre-receive` hook from gitlab's API

Answer (score 1):

If you have the branch name, you can use Gitlab API to check if a Merge Request is linked to that branch :

```
GET /merge_requests?source_branch={branch_name}
```

Merge Requests API doc here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-merge-requests

You can then parse the response to get the other information you need (MR ID, current SHA ... )